# How can new features be added to microstrategy built application?

Tags: java, microstrategy

I am currently working on an application which uses microstrategy and Java.
We want to implement some new features like maker checker to the application.
Is there any way to achieve it apart from using microstrategy SDK as we are not comfortable on microstrategy side.

Comment: What do you mean "maker checker"? Generally, if you want to add more functionality to MicroStrategy, you would have to use the SDK.

Comment: Maker Checker is breaking a process in two step process i.e. a transaction which required 1 user to complete the process will now require 2 users to complete the process.